# Can I ask for the 30 - 60 day extension for Thailand now that I am home?

Tags: tourist-visas, thailand, visa-extensions

I didn't know I could extend my visa time in Thailand an extra 30 to 60 days. Can I do so now to use later or how hard is it to get the Thailand one-year visa?

Comment: If you're no longer in Thailand, you don't need to extend your visa and most likely can't, but you probably can go to Thailand with a new visa just like the one you just used.  For us to analyze the possibilities open to you, however, it will help to know your nationality.

Answer (score 5):

You can't extend a visa that's expired, which is what happened when you left Thailand. If you need a visa to go to Thailand, you'll have to apply for a new one, and if you're visa exempt you can just go again.